# Counting substring occurrences in string[]

Tags: c#

Given a String array such as this:

```
string[]={"bmw"," ","1bmw"," "};
```

I need to count how often the substring `bmw` occurs in that array. In this example it occurs 2 times.

How do I write that in C#?

also i want to ignore the capital character,

sting[]={"bmw", "", "BMw","1bmw"}

then the count result is 3.

what should i do?

#

Thanks for everyone's answer.

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
var str = new string[] { "bmw", " ", "1bmw", " " };
var count = str.Count(s => s.Contains("bmw"));
```

the next code will return the count of case insensitive occurrences (as author mentioned in comments):

```
var count = str.Count(s =>
    s.IndexOf("bmw", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1
);
```

More about string comparisons could be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx).

Comment: hi, how about the sting[]={"bmw", "", "BMw","1bmw"} there is a "BMw" not exact same with "bmw" i also want to count this word in.

Answer (score 5):

Without LINQ

```
int counter = 0;

foreach(string item in string_array)
{
   if(item.IndexOf("bmw") > -1){
     counter++;

   }
}
```

Comment: hi, how about the sting[]={"bmw", "", "BMw","1bmw"} 
there is a "BMw" not exact same with "bmw"
i also want to count this word in.

Comment: @shaon-fan The easiest way to handle that would be to use ToLower() on each of the strings to search.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Linq for this like so:

```
var s = new string[] {"bmw", "1bmw"};
var result = s.Where(o=>o.Contains("bmw")).Count();
```

Comment: hi, how about the sting[]={"bmw", "", "BMw","1bmw"} there is a "BMw" not exact same with "bmw" i also want to count this word in.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C# 3, you can use LINQ:

```
var strings = {"bmw"," ","1bmw"," "};
var count = string.Where( s => s.IndexOf( "bmw" ) > -1 ).Count();
```

Otherwise a loop will work too:

```
string[] strings = {"bmw"," ","1bmw"," "};  
int count = 0;
foreach( string s in strings ) {
    if( s.IndexOf( "bmw" > -1 ) ) {
       count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, how about the sting[]={"bmw", "", "BMw","1bmw"} there is a "BMw" not exact same with "bmw" i also want to count this word in.

Comment: @shaon-fan: If you want case-insensitive comparison, just use: `IndexOf( "bmw", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )` - the `OrdinalIgnoreCase` parameter will match any casing in the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

One method using LINQ

```
static int CountOfString(IEnumerable<string> items, string substring, bool isCaseSensitive)
{
    StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.InvariantCulture;
    if (!isCaseSensitive)
        comparison = StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;

    return items.Count(item => item.IndexOf(substring, comparison) > -1);
}
```

Using it

```
string[] items = { "bmw", " ", "1bmw", " " };
int count = CountOfString(items, "bmw", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Case-insensitiveness makes it a little more verbose but still it's quite compact using following:

```
var str = new sting[]={"bmw", "", "BMw","1bmw"};
var count = str.Count(s => s.IndexOf("bmw", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1);
```